# What do I need to read .mat file in c++

Tags: c++, matlab

I want to read some .mat file containing nested structs to use the data for a QT-GUI. So I'm using QT Creator.

My problem right now is, that I don't know what Files I need to call the read functions. 
Right now I just very simply add **all *.h** files from *matlabroot/extern/include* and the file **libmat** and **libmx** from *matlabroot/bin/win64* to my sourcecode directory.

My code looks like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "mat.h"

int main()
{
    MATFile* pmat;

    std::string filename = "x.mat";
    const char* file = filename.c_str();

    printf("Reading file %s...\n\n", file);

    pmat = matOpen(file, "r");
    if (pmat == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening file %s\n", file);
        return (1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I always get the error **undefined reference to 'matOpen'** but matOpen should be in **mat.h**.

I just want to run a small minimal example to at least call some of the matlab c++ functions. So I need to know which files are really necessary to put in my working directory.

I'm not really experienced with using someone else's code.

Comment: What flags are you using to try to compile this? Did you link the appropriate libraries?

Comment: "Undefined reference" errors usually indicate a linker problem - usually omission of requisite libraries; sometimes a library ordering problem.

Comment: Unless matlab uses a `#pragma comment( lib, "somelibname.lib")` in the headers you added you will need to add the link to the matlab libraries.